# Why VGG16 "model summary" shows less [non]-trainable parameters in a non-shared network scenario for image similarity?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction, transfer-learning, vgg-net

I am working on an image similarity project. There are two types of images(i-e: camera images and another its corresponding sketch or CAD model).

The network will be trained to find the similarity/dissimilarity between the given images.

For this task, the pipeline work as follows:

The VGGNet-16 (without classification head) will be used as a feature extractor. I used two VGGNets(for each type of image).

```
vgg16_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()
vggcam_model = Sequential()
vggcad_model = Sequential()

for layer in vgg16_model.layers[:-4]:
        vggcam_model.add(layer)
        vggcad_model.add(layer)
```

Then I froze all the layers:

```
for vggcam_layers, vggcad_layers  in zip(vggcam_model.layers, vggcad_model.layers):
    vggcam_layers.trainable, vggcad_layers = (False, False)
```

Extracted feature vectors:

```
encoded_camfv = Flatten()(vggcam_model(cam_input))
encoded_cadfv = Flatten()(vggcad_model(cad_input))
```

This will produce a fixed size feature vector for each type of image.

Next, both feature vectors will be combined and put into the similarity network:

```
merge = concatenate([encoded_camfv, encoded_cadfv])

fc1 = Dense(1024, activation='relu', name='fc1')(merge)
fc2 = Dense(1024, activation='relu', name='fc2')(fc1)
output = Dense(1, activation='softmax', name='fc3')(fc2)

model = Model(inputs=[cam_input, cad_input], outputs=output)
print(model.summary())
```

The summary of the model:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 224, 224, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            (None, 224, 224, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_1 (Sequential)       (None, 7, 7, 512)    14714688    input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_2 (Sequential)       (None, 7, 7, 512)    14714688    input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)             (None, 25088)        0           sequential_1[1][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)             (None, 25088)        0           sequential_2[1][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 50176)        0           flatten_1[0][0]                  
                                                                 flatten_2[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
fc1 (Dense)                     (None, 1024)         51381248    concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                     (None, 1024)         1049600     fc1[0][0]                        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
fc3 (Dense)                     (None, 1)            1025        fc2[0][0]                        
==================================================================================================
Total params: 67,146,561
Trainable params: 52,431,873
Non-trainable params: 14,714,688
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
```

As I have used two VGG models one for each type of image. Why the number of non-trained parameters is only **14,714,688**. It should be **2 x Non-trainable params**.

In later stages, I unfroze the last convolutional block of the network and trained the similarity network along with last CONVO block.

```
for vggcam_layers, vggcad_layers in zip(vggcam_model.layers[15:], vggcad_model.layers[15:]):
    vggcam_layers.trainable, vggcad_layers = (True, True)
```

This also shows the same behavior. Is this the problem with code or in my understanding?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to make two instances of VGG for that to work, you only have a single instance and literally are using the same layers (and the same weights).

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro could you please mention where I need to make changes. Because according to my knowledge I have one network VGG16_model and two different instances vggcam_model and vggcad_model and both will learn different data representation before the flatten and concatination layers.

Comment: I tried two things one of them worked: 

1. Defined the models as: 

vggcam_model = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,
 input_tensor=Input(shape=(img_width, img_height, channels)))

vggcad_model = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,
 input_tensor=Input(shape=(img_width, img_height, channels)))
 
But while creating the model I got an error:

 Model(inputs=[cam_input, cad_input], outputs=output)

ValueError: The name "vgg16" is used 2 times in the model. All layer names should be unique.

Comment: 2. Next, I tried the following way and it worked:

vggcam_model = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,
 input_tensor=Input(shape=(img_width, img_height, channels)))
 
and for second model I used:

model = vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet')
vggcad_model = Sequential()
for layer in model.layers[:-4]:
    vggcad_model.add(layer)
 
This worked! 

However the first way is more conveninet. Is there any possibility to change the name?